# Парсинг чисел из ip адреса

Tags: java, ip

Требуется парсить числа из ip адреса, а потом их написать слитно в строку.
Делаю вот таким кодом.

```
String ips = ServerRuler.ip;
String ipes[] = ips.split(".");
System.out.println(ipes[0] + ipes[1] + ipes[2] + ipes[3]);
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: ips - пустая строка, очевидно

Comment: @Etki, не пустая. Она приходит с клиента.
Перед операций с ней вывожу ее на экран.
Прекрасно выводится, надо сказать.

Comment: @DenShDen, поставьте вывод на экран переменной `ips` непосредственно перед `split` и покажите её результат, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То, что вы указываете аргументом `split()` - это не последовательность символов, по которой надо разбить строку, а *регулярное выражение*. Поэтому точка воспринимается как метасимвол "любой символ". Насколько понимаю (беглый анализ метода не привел к точному пониманию), так как любой символ является разделителем, разделять остается нечего - вся строка состоит из одних разделителей. В любом случае тот шаблон разделения, который вы хотели использовать, будет выглядеть вот так:

```
ips.split("\\.");
```

Это экранирует вышеописанный метасимвол, который теперь будет играть роль обычной точки.

Answer (score 3):

Формулировка вашей задачи, на мой взгляд, сводится к "убрать точки из текстового представления IP-адреса". Соответственно решается в одну строку:

```
String ips = ServerRuler.ip.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```